# How do I represent the current time with a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, datetime, time

I was wondering if I could give the current time a varible and how to do it.
HTML.  It most likely uses a var statement but I don't know how to actually get the current time.

Comment: <script>
    var currentTime = new Date(); 
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var now = new Date(); // actual time
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing! If you google for 3 seconds you can get tons of articles.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not good at googling and I always get the wrong stuff.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

var dt = new Date();

var time = dt.getHours()+" : "+dt.getMinutes()

//Append current hours and minutes together. Append dt.getSeconds() to get current time upto the second.